# Get stroke color from Adobe Illustrator vector object

Tags: c#, .net, adobe

I am trying to get the stroke color of an Adobe Illustrator vector object using COM.Interop.Illustrator.

The code is fairly simple, just an iteration through objects:

```
        for (int i = 1; i < openedIllu.PathItems.Count+1; i++)
        {
            if(openedIllu.PathItems[i].Stroked){
                Console.WriteLine(openedIllu.PathItems[i].StrokeColor);
            }
        }
```

The object's stroke has a spot color asigned but the color type doesn't matter, the beahaviour is the same. The output is System.__ComObject.
The StrokeColor doesn't have any properties.

I tried to assign a color using the same property (openedIllu.PathItems[i].StrokeColor = "Black";) and this happend:

System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Operation is not supported on this platform.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it; It's like scratching your butt trough the ear:

```
            SpotColor color = new SpotColor();

            for (int i = 1; i < openedIllu.PathItems.Count+1; i++)
            {
                if (openedIllu.PathItems[i].Stroked)
                {
                    color = openedIllu.PathItems[i].StrokeColor;
                    Console.WriteLine($"sColor = {color.Spot.Name}");
                }
            }
```